# Update en modal CRUD

Tags: php, html, mysql, modal, crud

estoy realizando un crud sencillo, ya la parte de de crear, listar y borrar esta lista sin embargo la de update me esta dando bastante problema, estoy tratando de realizar la actualizacion mediante un formulario en un modal, pero al hacer click en el boton, de cualquiera de los registros, los valores que me muestra son los del primer registro indiferentemente de cual abra.

```
  <tbody>

    <?php while ( $resultado = $consulta->fetch_assoc() ){ ?>
     <tr>
     <th><?php echo $resultado['id'] ?></th>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['nombre'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['apellido'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['cedula'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['edad'] ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['email']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['especialidad']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['semestre']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $resultado['unidades_credito']?></td>
     <td><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $resultado['id'] ?>" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalupdate"><i class="fa fa-user-edit fa-2x"></i></a> </td>
     <td><a href="index.php?eliminar=delete&id=<?php echo $resultado['id']?>" onclick="return confirm('¿Esta seguro de eliminar este registro?');" title="Eliminar" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-2x"></i></a></td>

     </tr>

     <div class="modal" id="myModalupdate">
```

```
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title">Actualizacion de alumno</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
  </div>


  <div class="modal-body">
  <form action="crear.php" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $resultado['id'] ?>">
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $resultado['nombre'] ?>" name="nombre"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $resultado['apellido'] ?>" name="apellido"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="<?php echo $resultado['cedula'] ?>" name="cedula"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Edad" name="edad"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Email" name="email"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Especialidad" name="especialidad"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Semestre" name="semestre"><br>
 <input type="text" required="" placeholder="U.C" name="unidades_credito"><br><br>
 <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="button" value="Enviar" >

  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
  <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
```

Anexo captures de pantalla:
[image: La vista principal]
[image: Al posicionarse sobre el boton marca el id del registro]

[image: Al hacer click en el boton, muestra los datos del primer registro siempre, los coloque en el placeholder a modo de muestra]

Codigo del back:

```
           if (isset($_POST['button']))
                $registro = [
                    'id'=> $_POST['id'],
                    'nombre'=> $_POST['nombre'],
                    'apellido'=> $_POST['apellido'],
                    'cedula'=> $_POST['cedula'],
                    'edad'=> $_POST['edad'],
                    'email'=>$_POST['email'],
                    'especialidad'=>$_POST['especialidad'],
                    'semestre'=>$_POST['semestre'],
                    'unidades_credito'=>$_POST['unidades_credito']

                ];



        $consulta = 'UPDATE estudiantes SET
                        nombre = "'.$registro['nombre'].'",
                        apellido = "'.$registro['apellido'].'",
                        cedula = "'.$registro['cedula'].'",
                        edad = "'.$registro['edad'].'",
                        email = "'.$registro['email'].'",
                        especialidad = "'.$registro['especialidad'].'",
                        semestre = "'.$registro['semestre'].'",
                        unidades_credito = "'.$registro['unidades_credito'].'",
                        WHERE id = "'.$registro['id'].'"';



                        //Si la consulta se ejecuta correctamente se emite un mensaje de exito.
                        if ($conexion->query($consulta)) :
                            echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=index.php">';
                            echo "<script language='javascript'>
                            alert('Acutualizacion realizada satisfactoriamente.');
                            </script>";
                        else : //De lo contrario se muestra un error indicando que no se pudo ejecutar la consulta.
                            echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;URL=index.php">';
                            echo "<script language='javascript'>
                            alert('Error el registro no pudo ser actualizado, intentelo nuevamente.');
                            </script>";
                        endif;

                        $conexion->close();
```

Al hacer print_r sobre $consulta arroja la query asi:

UPDATE estudiantes SET nombre = "Deyxon2", apellido = "Ortiz", cedula = "26493221", edad = "20", email = "deyxon@gmail.com", especialidad = "Informatica", semestre = "6", unidades_credito = "10", WHERE id = "13"

Comment: ¿Dónde haces la obtención de los datos de ese ID en especifico? ¿Cómo es tu consulta?

Comment: Creo que no me he explicado bien, en el codigo aun no estoy pasando los datos para hacer la query del update, la idea es que al darle click en el boton, al abrir el modal el formulario que lleva adentro tenga los datos del registro en el que se hizo click, pero en todos me muestra solo los datos del primer registro el que tiene el id 1.

Comment: Ah, okay, ya te entendí. La manera en que lo deseas hacer no es la correcta.

Comment: Cual seria la manera correcta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera en que lo deseas hacer no es la manera correcta ni la más optima por que estás consumiendo muchos recursos innecesarios.

En este caso, crearás demasiados modales por cada alumno que se encuentre en tu tabla, ¿Por qué innecesarios? Porque ningún usuario que use tu sistema va a abrir uno por uno cada vez que se abra esa pantalla.

Mi recomendación es que utilices AJAX (Javascript) para hacer peticiones a tu backend y cada ves que obtengas algo, lo añadas al modal. Puedes ver un ejemplo [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/253311/12625). En ese ejemplo, se creo un JSON para simular la respuesta del backend.

---

El problema surge por que cada modal debe de tener un atributo HTML distinto llamado id. Como es tu caso, el id no es distinto y siempre se centra en el primer modal que aparece con ese mismo id.

Lo único que tendrías que hacer es añadir en el data-target el ID del usuario.

```
<td><a href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $resultado['id'] ?>" title="Editar datos" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalupdate<?php echo $resultado['id']?>"><i class="fa fa-user-edit fa-2x"></i></a> </td>
```

Y esto en tu modal (para que sepa a donde apuntar).

```
<div class="modal" id="myModalupdate<?php echo $resultado['id'] ?>">
```

Se me hizo un dificil explicarlo pero puedes leerte la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/). Ojo con la versión de Bootstrap que estás usando.

Comment: Es un trabajo escolar, no es algo que realmente vaya a entrar en produccion, por eso la optimizacion de recursos no importa tanto, aunque es cierto que seria mas optimo de la manera que dices con ajax, pero el profesor solo nos permitio usar php, mysql y boopstrap para la parte del front

Comment: Oh, ya. Entiendo. Igual podría servirte para un futuro y para que ya tengas una idea más plena. Si la respuesta fue correcta, ¿Podrías marcarla? Saludos! Cualquier otra duda, aqui estoy.

Comment: Ya logre solucionar para que se muestren los valores indicados de cada registro, sin embargo al pasar el formulario y verificarlo con isset, pasan todos los datos menos el id al hacer var_dump($registro); me arroja esto array(9) { ["id"]=> NULL ["nombre"]=> string(6) "prueba" ["apellido"]=> string(6) "prueba" ["cedula"]=> string(6) "252525" ["edad"]=> string(2) "25" ["email"]=> string(12) "pr@gmail.com" ["especialidad"]=> string(5) "prueb" ["semestre"]=> string(1) "5" ["unidades_credito"]=> string(1) "5" }

Comment: Te falta el atrributo name en tu input hidden

Comment: Muchas gracias bro el sueño me esta ganando y se me pasan detalles, sin embargo sigue saliendo una cosa tras otra, al comprobar los datos excelente todos llegan y estructura la consulta pero no hace el update, editare para que puedas ver el codigo del back

Comment: En el update de unidades_credito hay una coma.